# what's the difference of sqoop import to hdfs and to hive?

Tags: mysql, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I was able to use sqoop to import a mysql table "titles" to hdfs using command like this:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees --username=root -P --table=titles --target-dir=titles --m=1
```

Now I want to import to hive, if I use the following command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees --username=root -P --table titles --hive-import
```

I will be prompted that:

> Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/titles already exists

In hive, if I do a show tables I get the following:

```
hive> show tables;
OK
dept_emp
emp
myfirsthivetable
parted1emp
partitionedemp
```

You can see there is no table called titles in hive

I am confused at this, for the sqoop imported data, is there any 1 to 1 relationship between hdfs and hive? What's the meaning of the prompt?

Thank you for your enlighening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amit has pointed out, since you already created the HDFS directory in your first command, Sqoop refuses to overwrite the folder `titles` since it already contains data.

In your second command, you are telling Sqoop to import (once again) the whole table (which was already imported in the first command) into Hive. Since you are not specifying the `--target-dir` with the HDFS destination, Sqoop will try to create the folder `titles` under `/user/root/`. SInce this folder already exists, an error was raised.

When you tell Hive to show the tables, `titles` doesn't appear because the second command (with `hive-import`) was not successful, and Hive doesn't know anything about the data.  When you add the flag `--hive-import`, what Sqoop does under the hood is update the Hive metastore which is a database that has the metadata of the Hive tables, partitions and HDFS location.

You could do the data import using just one Sqoop command instead of using two different ones. If you delete the `titles` HDFS folder and you perform something like this:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees --username=root 
-P --table=titles --target-dir /user/root/titles --hive-import --m=1
```

This way, you are pulling the data from Mysql, creating the `/user/root/titles` HDFS directory and updating the metastore, so that Hive knows where the table (and the data) is.

But what if you wouldn't want to delete the folder with the data that you already imported? In that case, you could [create](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable) a new Hive table `titles` and specify the location of the data using something like this:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE title    
  [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  (...)
  LOCATION '/user/root/titles'
```

This way, you wouldn't need to re-import the whole data again, since it's already in HDFS.

Comment: Thank you Jaime for your detailed explanation. Everyone's help is  much appreciated here.

Comment: Just tried again by indicating target-dir=titles_new and the data was loaded into hive, and when I list the hive, I can see the newly added table; however, if I list it in a different way: `[root@xie1 Desktop]# hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root`, it is NOT there. I also tried: `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/user/titles_new` and I was prompted that No such file or directory.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a typo. The `--target-dir` parameter should have the whole path to the directory. In this case, `--target-dir=/user/root/titles`. Could you check if the imported table is in `/titles`?

Comment: Thanks.  In the above comment I already said No such file or directory. :)

Comment: Yes, but in the comment you are checking `/user/titles_new`. Is it anything under `/titles_new`?

Comment: No, checked: `hdfs://localhost:9000/titles_new` and `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/titles_new`, both says No such file or directory

Comment: Could you please execute `hdfs dfs -ls -R /`? This should list all hdfs files from /, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you Jaime, I found it: `drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-06-28 22:14 /user/root/titles
`, but as you can see the size is 0, maybe it was actually not a success? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: That's normal, when you list the files and directories in HDFS, directories will appear with a size of 0. If you want to check the actual size of the directory, you can use  `hdfs dfs -du -s /user/root/titles`. Under the `/user/root/titles/` path, you should see other files and directories with the data.

Comment: Thank you, got it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table on hive it eventually creates a directory on HDFS, as you already ran the hadoop import first hence a directory named "titles" already been created on HDFS.

Either can you delete the `/user/root/titles` directory from HDFS and ran the hive import command again or use `--hive-table` option while import.

You can refer to the sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root` and `hdfs dfs -ls` give exactly the same result?

Comment: goto your hadoop installation dir and run bin/hadoop fs -ls /user/root or bin/hadoop fs -lsr /user/root